# An exercise for axion from Mark Srednicki's QFT book

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, axion

In Mark's QFT book, exercise 94.2(d) says

> In eq.(94.10), we should replace $\theta$ by $\theta+a/f...$.

eq.(94.10) is just the mass term
\begin{equation}
M=Diag\{m_{u},m_d\}e^{-i\theta/2},
\end{equation}
which appears in the chiral lagrangian $...+Tr\{MU\}+H.c+...$

The [solution](https://pdf-drive.com/pdf/Srednicki20M.20-20Quantum20field20theory20-20solutions20manual2028200629.pdf) by Mark himself says

> $\theta+a/f$ is invariant, and is the variable that should appear in
> the low-energy theory...

I can work out $\theta+a/f$ is unchanged under the *Peccei-Quinn symmetry*, but I cannot understand the logic here. How does this invariance lead to the replacement $\theta \rightarrow \theta+a/f$? Any help will be appreciated. Recall the *Peccei-Quinn symmetry* is
\begin{equation}
\Psi\rightarrow e^{-i\alpha \gamma^5}\Psi,~~~\Phi \rightarrow e^{-2i\alpha}\Phi,
\end{equation}
which also shifts the $\theta$ term $\theta F\tilde{F}$ in QCD by $\theta \rightarrow \theta+2\alpha$.

Comment: Using Srednicki or Prof. Srednicki would be more appropriate than the familiar Mark.

Comment: @Oбжорoв I don't see any problem, he's called Mark Srednicki? So it's ok to call him Mark Srednicki

Comment: @RenatoRenatoRenato there is no problem. I am probably just old-fashioned.